# Subtract two observableArrays in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ko.observablearray, subtraction

How can I get substracted value (or difference) between two observablearrays.

For eg.

```
AllUsers = [{UserKey01,User_ABC},{UserKey02,User_DEF},{UserKey03,User_GHI},{UserKey04,User_JKL}]
SpecialUsers = [{UserKey01,User_ABC},{UserKey02,User_DEF}]
```

And I need

```
NonSpecialUsers = [{UserKey03,User_GHI},{UserKey04,User_JKL}]
```

Mentioned below is the code I am trying with:

```
function UserViewModel(userKey,userName) {
        var self = this;
        self.UserKey = ko.observable(0);
        self.UserName = ko.observable(0);
    }

self.AllUsers = observableArray();
self.SpecialUsers = observableArray();

self.NonSpecialUsers  = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var usrs = ko.observableArray();
            for (var i = 0; i < self.SpecialUsers().length; i++) {
                var assignedUser = self.SpecialUsers()[i];

                var x =  ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.AllUsers(), function (item) {
                    return item.UserKey() != assignedUser.UserKey();

                });
                usrs.push(x);
            }
            return usrs;
        });
```

With this I am getting array of non-specialusers*specialusers:
i.e.

```
[[{UserKey01,User_ABC},{UserKey02,User_DEF}],[{UserKey01,User_ABC},{UserKey02,User_DEF}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it:

```
var filteredUsrs = $.grep(self.SpecialUsers(), function (el) { return el });
var filteredUserKeys = ko.toJS(filteredUsers).map(function (elem) { return elem.UserKey; })
return $.grep(self.AllUsers(), function (u) { return filteredUserKeys.indexOf(u.UserKey()) == -1; });
```

Not sure if there is a better way of doing it though.